# Spring : the 404 error only with the vo class as a parameter in spring controller

Tags: spring, controller, http-status-code-404, value-objects, modelattribute

I'm making a site with Spring framework.
the problem is the 404 error occurs only when I put the VO as a parameter. 
I put the VO as a @ModelAttribute in controller.

I made the VO's properties with two tables columns together.
I guess the problem is caused because of the 1-VO matches 2-Table, because
when I use the same way with 1-VO mathces 1-table, there's no error.

please let me know the reason exactly why this error occurs if anybody knows it.

here are the sources.

this is the 1st table matching to VO properties.

```
TAN_ASE_NO          int(11)
ASE_TP_DT_CD        int(11)
NM                  varchar(20)
XPN                 tinytext
WST_DT              date
ASE_ST_DT_CD        varchar(5)
TAN_ASE_CR_NO       int(11)
TAN_ASE_ENTP_INFO   int(11)
TAN_ASE_AD_FILE_NO  int(11)
TAN_ASE_CHRPS_NO    int(11)
```

this is the 2nd table matching to VO properties.

```
TAN_ASE_NO_HDW  int(11)
HDW_FLG         varchar(20)
OS_TP           varchar(20)
AMG_FLG         varchar(20) 
HDW_MODL_NM     tinytext
HDW_PST         varchar(30)
HOSTNM          varchar(30)
IP              varchar(20)
US_USE          varchar(20)
PRD_CMP         varchar(30) 
MDL             varchar(30) 
CLK             varchar(10)
CPU_CNT         int(11)
CR_CNT          int(11)
MEMR            int(11)
STRG_TOT_CAPA   int(11)
ADMR            varchar(20)
```

I made a VO class with these 2-table, to insert the data related to these tables.

```
public class HDW {
private int tan_ase_no;
private int ase_tp_dt_cd;
private String nm;
private String xpn;
private String wst_dt;
private int ase_st_dt_cd;
private int tan_ase_cr_no;
private int tan_ase_entp_info;
private int tan_ase_ad_file_no;
private int tan_ase_chrps_no;
private int tan_ase_no_hdw;
private String hw_flg;
private String os_tp;
private String amg_flg;
private String hw_modl_nm;
private String hw_pst;
private String hostnm;
private String ip;
private String us_use;
private String prd_cmp;
private String mdl;
private String clk;
private int cpu_cnt;
private int cr_cnt;
private int memr;
private int strg_tot_capa;
private String admr;
```

(the setters/getters are omitted.)

lastly, here's the controller source part.

```
public String addHdw(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("command") HDW hdw) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("$$Test for hdwControl");
    System.out.println(hdw);
    hdwDAO.addHdw(hdw);
    return "redirect:/index.do";
}
```

when I remove the @modelAttribute("command") HDW hdw parameter, 
the console shows me the "$$Test for hdwControl" without any problem.

what should i do to resolve the problem?

** here's the addtion sources **

I matched the @ModelAttribute to html input fields of course.

```
<form name="form1">
<div class="containerRight">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h2>H/W</h2>
            <input type="hidden" name="tan_ase_no" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="tan_ase_no_hdw" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="ase_tp_dt_cd" name="ase_tp_dt_cd" value="401">
        </header>
        <div class="articleBody">
            <div class="articleBodyLeft">
                <section>
                    <h3>BASIC</h3>
                    <table class="tableArticle">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="120">NAME
                            </td>
                            <td><input name="nm" type="text" id="nm" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>FLAG</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="hw_flg" id="codeList600">                         
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>OS</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="os_tp" id="codeList700">
                                </select>
                                <label>*VIRTUALIZATION FLAG : </label>
                                <select name="amg_flg" id="codeList800">
                                </select> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="120">MODEL</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="hw_modl_nm" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="120">COMPANY</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="tan_ase_entp_info"  value="">  
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="120">POSITION</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="hw_pst" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="xpn" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>STATUS</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="ase_st_dt_cd" value="501">OPERATION
                                <input type="radio" name="ase_st_dt_cd" value="502">UNUSED
                                <input type="radio" name="ase_st_dt_cd" value="503">DISCARD
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DICARD DATE</td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="wst_dt" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h3>INFO</h3>
                    <table class="tableArticle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hostname</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="hostnm" id="hostnm" value=""> 
                                <label for="ip">IP : </label><input type="text" name="ip" id="ip">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ADMIN Agent</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="admr" value="1001">SERVER
                                <input type="checkbox" name="admr" value="1002">SECURITY
                                <input type="checkbox" name="admr" value="1003">BACK-UP
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>USE</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="us_use" value="901">DEVELOP
                                <input type="checkbox" name="us_use" value="902">TEST
                                <input type="checkbox" name="us_use" value="903">VERIFY
                                <input type="checkbox" name="us_use" value="904">OPERATE
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h3>제원</h3><input type="button" value="TEST">
                    <table class="tableArticle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>CPU</td>
                            <td>
                                PRODUCTION : <input type="text" name="prd_cmp" value="">
                                MODEL : <input type="text" name="mdl" value=""> 
                                Clock : <input type="text" name="clk" value=""> GHz
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CPU QUANTITY</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="cpu_cnt" value="">CPU × <input type="text" name="cr_cnt" value="">Core = 48 Core
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memory</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="memr" value="">GB
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2">DISK IN</td>
                            <td>TOTAL CAPA : 500 GB <input type="button" value="MANAGEMENT" onclick="popUp($('#tan_ase_no').val(),$('#ase_tp_dt_cd').val())"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>= 100GB × 2 + 200GB × 2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2">DISK-OUT(Mount)</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value="INFO">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>                       
                    </table>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h3>Volume</h3><input type="button" value="INFO">
                    <table class="tableArticle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>TOTAL</td>
                            <td>
                                10.,246 GB
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h3>ADDED FILE</h3><input type="file" value="ADD">
                    <table class="tableArticle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>ADDED LIST</td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" name="tan_ase_ad_file_no" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h3>MANAGER</h3>
                    <table class="tableArticle">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Main</td>
                            <td><input type="search" results="10" name="tan_ase_chrps_no"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sub</td>
                            <td><input type="search" results="10" name=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="articleBodyRight">
                <section>
                    <h3>CONTRACT</h3>
                    <table class="tableArticleRel">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name<input type="hidden" name="tan_ase_cr_no" value=""></td>
                            <td><a href="#"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>DATE</td>
                            <td>2012-01-05</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>                  
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="btnDetailArea">
            <button type="button">Send Message</button> 
            <button type="button" id="btnEdit" onclick="setEditMode()">EDIT</button>
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="SAVE">
            <button type="button">CLOSE</button>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

here's the xml file (iBatis sqlMap) includes the query to insert the HDW to Database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<insert id="addHdw" parameterClass="Hdw">
    <![CDATA[
        insert into tan_ase values (0,#ase_tp_dt_cd#,#nm#,#xpn#,#wst_dt#,#ase_st_dt_cd#,
        #tan_ase_cr_no#,#tan_ase_entp_info#,#tan_ase_ad_file_no#,#tan_ase_chrps_no#)
    ]]>
    <selectKey keyProperty="tan_ase_no_hdw" resultClass="Integer">
        select LAST_INSERT_ID()
    </selectKey>
        insert into hdw values (#tan_ase_no_hdw#,#hw_flg#,#os_tp#,#amg_flg#,#hw_modl_nm#,#hw_pst#,
        #hostnm#,#ip#,#us_use#,#prd_cmp#,#mdl#,#clk#,#cpu_cnt#,#cr_cnt#,#memr#,#strg_tot_capa#,#admr#)
```

Answer (score 0):

@ModelAttribute annotation on request handlers is typically used to bind HTML form input into a particular type (HDW class in your case). It does not handle mapping with your database whatsoever.

The 404 error you're getting is probably Spring failing to bind because you didn't post all the required fields

If you think your problem is with ORM (object relational mapping), investigate your persistence configuration (Hibernate / JPA / etc)

Comment: thank you for ur answer, but I actually did matching to html input fields with ModelAttribute, so I added that codes.